# Why the Object browser window is doesn't show anything

Tags: wmi, objectbrowser

i have downloaded wmi tools from microsoft page, when i am opening the wmi object browser, it shows like this

[image]

So how to view the event details of local system by using wmi.

Answer (score 2):

The [wmi tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24045) uses an activex control, so you must use Internet Explorer browser to open it.

Comment: Then change the IE security to allow ActiveX execution.

Comment: How to do that. can you help me.